# Get two queries in one - Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've been struggling, and couldn't find the right answers by myself.

For example, I have two separated associations

`Profile` that **belongs_to** `User`

`Comment` that **belongs_to** `User`

Both `Profile` and `Comment` have a **user_id** foreign key

Through `Comment` I can easily access user like `Comment.first.user` for example. But I can't do like *Comment.first.user.profile* (How can I do this?)
Can I join the results in a single query just with the user_id? Like Comment.joins .. ? I just want to know if this is possible, and if I can get some references I can do a research.

For example, I have this query for User.find(1)

```
id:12 | email:firefox@email.com
```

And I have this query for User.find(1).profiles

```
name: Fire | lastname: Fox | id_user: 12
```

Is it possible to obtain a result like this in ActiveRecord?

```
email:firefox@email.com | name: Fire | lastname: Fox
```

Also, can I do this with .all, instead of with .find or .where?

**Comment model**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Profile model**

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**User model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile
  has_many :projects
  has_many :comments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end
```

Comment: You should also have in `User` model `has_many :comments` and `has_one : profile` or something like that. Then you should be able to do `Comment.first.user.profile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sol 1**: If you want to fetch it in one query

You need to join `Profile` through `User` and you can query like this

```
Comment.joins(user: :profile)
  .select('users.email', 'profiles.name', 'profiles.lastname')
  .where(id: 123)
```

---

**Sol 2**: You just need to add a `through` association

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :profile, through: :user
end
```

and now you can access it like

```
comment = Comment.first
comment.user.email        #=> "firefox@email.com"
comment.profile.name      #=> "Fire"
comment.profile.lastname  #=> "Fox"
```

---

You can also use `delegate` but that will fire 2 queries

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile
  has_many :projects
  has_many :comments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

  delegate :name, :lastname, to: :profile, allow_nil: true
end
```

And now you can directly call `name` and `lastname` on user

```
comment = Comment.first
comment.user.email        #=> "firefox@email.com"
comment.user.name         #=> "Fire"
comment.user.lastname     #=> "Fox"
```

Comment: It's more simple that what I have imagined. The last solution it seems easier and elegant, even though it fires two queries. Im gonna do some tests here. Thanks a lot!